# Use `dplyr` to sum all of the lagging values

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to sum all of the lagging values in a group.

Using `cars` for example data;

```
#This returns what I want
for (i in 1:nrow(cars)) {
  First<-which(cars$speed==cars[i,"speed"])[1]
  cars[i,"DistSum"]<-sum(cars[First:i,"dist"], na.rm = T)
}

head(cars)
```

However, I do not want to use a for loop for this, and I would like the following to return what I want. If I could get `lag` to return all of the previous values in a group that should do the trick.

```
#dplyr version that does not work
cars <- (cars %>% 
                 dplyr::group_by(speed) %>%
                 dplyr::mutate(DistSum = sum(lag(dist))) %>%
                   ungroup())
```

Another way of thinking of it might be that I need `sum(lag(dist, n = ALL))`.

Comment: @AndreWildberg that will sum everything. I need it to be iterative (e.g., within a group the third value would be the sum of values 1 through 3 and the fourth value would be the sum of values 1 through 4, etc.) .

Comment: I'm unable to install the `cars` package to test, but have you tried `cumsum`?

Comment: @ChristianMillion, Yes, that should do it. I should have known better. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
cars %>% 
    group_by(speed) %>%
    mutate(DistSum = cumsum(dist)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    head()
```